# DATEDIFF creating function for php code

Tags: php

I am trying to convert the following MYSQL SELECT code in  to php code: `DATEDIFF(date, NOW()) <= 31` basicaly if the date is less than or equal to 31 days do the rest.

So far what I have done is the following

```
$today = new DateTime('now');
$date = $row['date'];
$diff = date_diff($date,$today);
```

and than inside if cycle I have the condition: `if ($diff <= 31)`

My Sql date column is only specified as a Date not DateTime I am getting the following error and I am wondering how I can get calculated the date only

```
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\c.php on line 299
bool(false) 
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\c.php on line 299
bool(false)
```

Aditional Information which makes the answers bellow to not be working is that in my SQL query I am preformating the date with `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d %b %Y') as date`

Any help will be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of `$row['date']`?

Comment: string(11) "04 Sep 2013" string(11) "12 Dec 2013" string(11) "12 Dec 2013"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the database data to a `DateTime` object as well before you do `date_diff()` on it.

```
$today = new DateTime('now');
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
$diff = date_diff($date,$today);
```

Now realize that since `$diff` is a `DateInterval` object, and you only care about the days component, you can evaluate like this:

```
if ($date->days <= 31) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: looks interesting solution but after the query is selecting the date here is what is inside the the $row['date'] string(11) "04 Sep 2013" string(11) "12 Dec 2013" string(11) "12 Dec 2013"  which is formated with DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d %b %Y') as date

Comment: That date format is not directly accepted by DateTime constructor.  You have a few options.  You can remove the `DATE_FORMAT` from the query.  You can change the `DATE_FORMAT` in the query to match one of those directly supported - see link http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php.  You can use `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y', $row['date'])` to create the `DateTime` object for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$today = new DateTime('now');
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
$diff = $date->diff($today)->days;
```

date_diff expects both arguments to be DateTime objects. Thats what it is complaining about. 
date_diff or Datetime::diff return a DateInterval, you can get the days from the days member variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm:

```
    $then = new DateTime('2010-05-30');//example, you could use $row['date']
    $now = new DateTime();//now
    $delta = $now->diff($then);

    $data = array(
        'year' => $delta->y,
        'month' => $delta->m,
        'day' => $delta->d,
        'hour' => $delta->h,
        'minute' => $delta->i,
        'second' => $delta->s
    );

    //now 
    if($data['day'] <= 31)
    {
       //do the stuff
    }
```

Comment: gettin error on the $days code: Notice: Undefined variable: years in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\c.php on line 296
Notice: Undefined variable: months in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\c.php on line 296
Notice: Undefined variable: years in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\c.php on line 296

error on: $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));//calculate

Comment: the result of $days is float(0) float(0) float(0)

Comment: @JohnSiniger, Try this. I had implemented strtotime twice.

Comment: Thanks, but right now it is calculating only the days in the current month. I want it to calculated Year, Monnth and Day. Basicaly if the date is after 2 months to calcuclate 60 days.

Comment: I think this is the best answer to your need